# Get financial year start date and end date based on alias in sql server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, select

I am having table containing two columns one for month and other for year. Based on these two columns I want all records for that financial year. For eg. if month is 10 and year is 2014 then offcourse its financial year will be FY 01StApr14 - 31stMar15.

How do I write a SQL select query to get all the records which were created between FY 01stApr14-31stMar15 available in that table based on month and year.

M trying below query but getting error messge as 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.'

```
with cte as
(
select id,iono,iomonth,ioyear,
        convert(datetime,'01/'+right('00' + convert(varchar(10),iomonth,2),2) 
        + '/' +convert(varchar(4),IOyear),103) as FinDate from iodetails where iono=12345
)
select month(findate),* from cte where iono=12345 and
findate between 
case 
when month(findate)>=4 
then  convert(datetime,'01/'+'04'+ '/' +convert(varchar(4),IOyear),103) and 
        convert(datetime,'31/'+ '03' + '/' +convert(varchar(4),IOyear+1),103)
        else
 convert(datetime,'01/'+'04'+ '/' +convert(varchar(4),IOyear),103)  and 
    convert(datetime,'31/'+ '03' + '/' +convert(varchar(4),IOyear),103)
            end
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your requirements correctly, you might try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
 WHERE year(dateadd(q, -1, mydate)) = 2014
```

This will subtract 1 quarter (3 months) from the value of `mydate` and extract the year. So `31 Mar 2015` becomes `31 Dec 2014` after the subtraction, which when the year is extracted is 2014.

**Oops** my apologies, I see that you have two columns, month and year. In that case you might try this:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
  WHERE year(dateadd(q, -1, cast(cast(mymonth AS char) + '/01/' + cast(myyear AS char) AS datetime))) = 2014
```

That is probably not the most efficient way of doing it however.

**UPDATE per my comments**

Here is how you might created a computed column on your table:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable
  ADD mydate AS cast(cast(mymonth AS char) + '/01/' + cast(myyear AS char) AS datetime)
```

Comment: I am not having date field in table. Only Month, year and some additional fields. I have tried to concatenate and get the date as alias but how do I write condition on alias and get all records of resulted financial year.

Comment: You can write the condition on the alias if you do a subquery. But maybe a better option is to create a computed column which calculates the date based on month and year?

Comment: Now m trying using CTE for condition on alias, since we cannot alter table. code  mentioned on question. but getting error 'Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'.'

Comment: getting error message as ''Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tableA 
WHERE CAST((CAST(YearCol AS VARCHAR(10)) + (CAST(MonthCol AS VARCHAR(10))) AS INT) 
      BETWEEN CAST((CASE WHEN @V_Month BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN CAST((CAST(@V_Year AS VARCHAR(10)) + '04') AS INT) 
                         WHEN @V_Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN CAST((CAST(@V_Year - 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '04') AS INT) 
                         ELSE '' 
                     END
                   ) AS INT)
        AND CAST((CASE WHEN @V_Month BETWEEN 4 AND 12 THEN CAST((CAST(@V_Year + 1 AS VARCHAR(10)) + '03') AS INT) 
                       WHEN @V_Month BETWEEN 1 AND 3 THEN CAST((CAST(@V_Year AS VARCHAR(10)) + '03') AS INT) 
                       ELSE '' 
                  END
                 ) AS INT);
```